# How to pass percentage of two django db field as a template tag

Tags: html, django

I have two fields in my django db which called `like` and `dislike`. I want to pass I need to pass the average of these two values to the template to be used as the `width` of `<div style="width:x%">`.

in views.py:

```
def PostListView(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    context['posts'] = posts
    return render(request, 'app/mytemplate.html', context)
```

and in template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
   <div class="ratings-css-top" style="width: {% widthratio post.like post.dislike 100 %}">
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

how to pass this average value of fields as a width? `like % (like + dislike ) * 100`

Comment: So your `Post` objects have two integer fields `like` and `dislike`?

Comment: Yes two fields in this object are like and dislike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`.annotate()`** [Djanog-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the queryset with:

```
from django.db.models import F

def PostListView(request):
    posts = Post.objects.annotate(
        total_like=F('like') + F('dislike')
    )
    context['posts'] = posts
    return render(request, 'app/mytemplate.html', context)
```

The `Post` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.total_like` that is the sum of `.like` and `.dislike`. We can then use this in the template:

```
<div style="width: {% widthratio post.like post.total_like 100 %}%"  class="ratings-css-top">
```

Comment: Just curious to know shouldn't we add `.all()` to queryset for retrieving other fields?

Comment: @J2015: no, `.all()` means you want to retrieve *all* records. But you do not have to use that if you call another queryset command. But you can, `.all()` basically makes a copy of the queryset.